# Pygame function with loops

Tags: python, pygame

Okay, so I am writing a script that controls the motors using a sbc motor shield board with my raspberry pi 3b.

The issue I am having is that if I just run the script a window will pop up for a split second allowing to press the a key to move the motor forward or any other keys that I have already defined within the script but it only last for a second before the window auto exits and I am returned to the terminal.

Now when I attempt to add a loop to keep the code running the window will stay open however it no longer recognizes when I press a key defined in the script.. I have spent hours researching and modifying the script I have wrote and have not been able to find a solution. I am very new to python and I appreciate any input given.

Also I am running python 3.6 thanks in advance

```
 import pygame
 import sys
 import pygame.locals
 import PiMotor
 import time

 m1 = PiMotor.Motor("MOTOR1",1)
 m2 = PiMotor.Motor("MOTOR2",1)


pygame.init()
(width, height) = (300, 200)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Johnny, motor controls!')
pygame.event.pump() 

for event in pygame.event.get():
if event.type == pygame.locals.QUIT:




 if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
 if event.key == pygame.K_a:

           m1.forward(100), time.sleep(0)
  if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
  if event.key == pygame.K_a:
      m1.stop()
  if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
  if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:

            m1.forward(100)
   if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
      if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
       m1.stop()
```

Comment: indentation matters in python, so could you please fix it? Also, it seems there's something missing between `if event.type == pygame.locals.QUIT:` and `if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a `while True:` when you get the events and check when to quit.

If you tried it and it didn't work maybe you had your indentation wrong? I see that it is wrong now in the code that you posted.

Something like:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.locals.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                m1.forward(100), time.sleep(0) # BTW, do you really need this sleep?
            [... Rest of your code ...]
```

Comment: I guess it was a mix of both issues, I added the code from above and re-done my indentations and now the code works. I am not really sure why I had the time.sleep(0) but no I didn't need it.. Now I am moving on to figuring out how to stop one track while keep the other moving.. I appreciate the help...